# How do I install Ubuntu onto a 32gb USB drive in legacy mode?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, portable

I have a pc with Windows 10 64 bit and I'm fairly certain it's installed in legacy mode for booting. I heard somewhere that in order to install Ubuntu on my flash drive, I need to have it installed in the same boot mode as Windows. I want my Ubuntu installation to be 100% portable, so I want to have a partition for Ubuntu only and the rest for random files and stuff.

I tried doing the Ubuntu installation on my USB drive previously but the error stated that GRUB couldn't be installed so the OS can't boot. This is why I think I need legacy booting. I can very easily be wrong about this.

*Edit:* Forgot to mention I'm doing the installation via DVD so I want to use the DVD only if possible. If it isn't possible because of some special ISO I need then that's perfectly fine

**TL;DR: I want a fully portable Ubuntu installation with legacy booting**

If it's important, my specs are listed below:

-Ryzen 5 1500x

-16gb 2400 RAM

-Radeon R9 290x

-ASRock micro-atx motherboard

-2tb HDD

-500gb Samsung 850 EVO

Comment: So you want a live USB then? With a data partition, optionally with persistence?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what all that means. I'm relatively new to Linux

Answer (score 0):

To determine if your motherboard is set to boot in legacy mode, you will have to go into your motherboard's UEFI/BIOS settings and see.  Usually, you can hold down the DEL key during bootup to make this happen.

However, as someone who's tried to do this before, it probably won't work, or your performance on the USB drive will be very poor. :(  It could install fine, but you might encounter random freezes/hangups when you're running ubuntu.

Comment: While writes to flash drives are slow, once you load an app into memory it runs just as well. Flash drives also have limited lives. I use mine more for emergency boot or sometimes tests, but do change settings to reduce writes.https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator If you cannot unplug drive, just use Something Else install option, booted in BIOS mode, and be sure to install grub to flash drive, not internal drive default.